# Django InMemoryUploadedFile and asynchronous tasks

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, large-file-upload

I have a django application on which I upload several files of huge size.
Once in my view, I want to do an asynchronous task on those files:

```
def my_view(request):
    Thread(target=_my_task, args=[request.FILES]).start())
    return redirect(my_url)
```

The problem is, by the time I uses the files in my thread, the main request has finished and the request object is deleted, alongside the InMemoryUploadedFile objects contained in it, and I get an IO exception:

```
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
```

How can I force the persistence of those files without writing them in my filesystem ?

Comment: That is one of the reasons why you don't do async tasks with threads in this way. use a proper task queue.

Comment: I understand using service like Celeri would be better but how does it help with the file closure problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I force the persistence of those files without writing them in my filesystem ?

Short answer: you can't.

Longest answer: you *could* pass the files contents instead of the file objects, but this is unsafe at best (if anything goes wrong you loose your data) and cumbersome (when you'll switch to a proper task queue - threading is NOT the proper ways to run async tasks in Django - you'll find out that passing mega or gigabytes of binaray data as tasks argument doesn't work well, to say the least).

TL;DR: save your files to disk one way or another (preferably on your filesystem, that's what it's for) and use a proper async task queue.